# SFTP's "get" needs write permission

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

I'm connecting to a server using sftp through console. I'm trying to download a folder which has some files without write permission for anyone. When I use *get*, those files throw an error that says I need write permissions, but the rest download fine.

It seems to be a problem with the console program, I tried WinSCP and it works fine, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it from a terminal without changing permissions.

The local system runs Windows 7 with Cygwin, the remote one Ubuntu 12.04.

Example:

```
Couldn't open local file "website/sites/default/default.settings.php" for writing: Permission denied
Download of file /var/www/website/sites/default/default.settings.php to website/sites/default/default.settings.php failed
```

EDIT:

Permissions on remote server:

```
website/             755
sites/               775
default/             555
default.setting.php  664
```

The local directory in which I start *sftp* has 755 permissions. After the *get*, files and directories seem to retain the same permissions they had on the remote server, so since *default* has no write permissions, nothing can be downloaded into it.

How can I *get* files without retaining the original permissions?

Comment: The error is likely to refer to the place where you're getting the files *to*.  Check that you have write permission in the directory where you're starting the `sftp` client.

Comment: Please include a dump (or screenshot) of the console. What platform are you on? I assume it's OpenSSH `sftp`, right?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the permissions on the local directory `website/sites/default` and the file `website/sites/default/default.settings.php`?

Comment: How exactly are you running sftp? What command-line options are you using?

Comment: @Kenster just sftp -P <port> <user>@<host>, then get -r /var/www/website

Comment: What if the remote server blocks write permissions on the directories you're trying to recursively copy? Is there any way to force things to copy with certain permissions? (Umask only block perms, doesn't grant).

Answer (score 2):

Running the console program as administrator solved this problem, for me, on Windows 10. I use git bash. As @Flup said, you must have write permission in the directory where you start the `sftp` client.